# Whitelist kube-apiserver with Network Policy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

What is the best way to define a rule that allows egress only to the kube-apiserver with a Network Policy?

While there's a `Service` resource for the kube-apiserver, there's not `Pods`, so as far as I know this can't be done with labels. With IP whitelisting, this isn't guaranteed to work across clusters. Is there any recommended practice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the IP address of the apiserver. You cannot use labels.
To find the IP address of the apiserver run:
`kubectl cluster-info`

Look for a line like this in the output:
`Kubernetes master is running at https://<ip>`
This is the IP address of your apiserver IP.

The network policy should look like this (assuming the apiserver IP is 34.76.197.27):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: egress-apiserver
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 34.76.197.27/32
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
```

[The policy above applies to all pods in the namespaces it is applied to](https://orca.tufin.io/netpol/?yaml=apiVersion:%20networking.k8s.io%2Fv1%0Akind:%20NetworkPolicy%0Ametadata:%0A3name:%20egress-apiserver%0Aspec:%0A3podSelector:%20%7B%7D%0A3policyTypes:%0A3-%20Egress%0A3egress:%0A3-%20to:%0A5-%20ipBlock:%0A9cidr:%2034.76.197.27%2F32%0A5ports:%0A5-%20protocol:%20TCP%0A7port:%20443%0A).
To select specific pods, edit the podSelector section with the tags of the pods that require apiserver access:

```
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apiserver-allowed
```

Remember that the default egress policy is ALLOW ALL which means other pods will still have access to the apiserver.
[You can change this behavior by adding a "BLOCK ALL" egress policy per namespace](https://orca.tufin.io/netpol/?yaml=apiVersion:%20networking.k8s.io%2Fv1%0Akind:%20NetworkPolicy%0Ametadata:%0A3name:%20deny-all-egress%0Aspec:%0A3podSelector:%20%7B%7D%0A3policyTypes:%0A3-%20Egress%0A) but remember not to block access to the DNS server and other essential services.
[For more info see "Egress and DNS (Pitfall!)" in this post](https://medium.com/@reuvenharrison/an-introduction-to-kubernetes-network-policies-for-security-people-ba92dd4c809d).

Note that in some cases there may be more than one apiservers (for scalability) in which case you will need to add all the IP addresses.

Comment: A bit unforunately, this is the answer. It's a bit annoying because it doesn't work across clusters.

Answer (score 1):

Two options comes to my mind.

**1)** Create `NetworkPolicy` with default deny all `egress` traffic with `Kubernetes-apiservice` IP range exception.

Due to some restarts, service IP might be changed that is better to use IP range.
In that case, you need to whitelist kubernetes `service IP` and `Endpoint IP`.

[This docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-egress-traffic) providing example with denying all `egress` traffic. You will need to modify this example to add this address as exception.
It will look like this.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-egress
  #optional namespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
      cidr: <kube-apiserver-IP-range>
    - port: <svc-port>
      protocol: <svc-protocol>
```

I would advise you to check [this](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/network-policy/) article.

**2)** Create `service` with static IP which will forward traffic to `kubernetes-apiserver`.

Service which would run `kubectl proxy` to apiserver.

**How to determine kube-apiserver**

In each cluster as default you will be able to see one service. For example in `kubeadm` it is kubernetes

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   15d
```

If you will describe it, you will get `endpoint`.

```
$ kubectl describe svc kubernetes
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.166.0.30:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

If you will check pods from `kube-system` namespace, the most of them have IP which is kubernetes service endpoint.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-5644d7b6d9-7sm4d               1/1     Running   3          15d   10.32.0.3     ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
coredns-5644d7b6d9-g42g6               1/1     Running   3          15d   10.32.0.2     ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
etcd-ubus-kubeadm                      1/1     Running   3          15d   10.166.0.30   ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-ubus-kubeadm            1/1     Running   3          15d   10.166.0.30   ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-ubus-kubeadm   1/1     Running   3          15d   10.166.0.30   ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-57r9m                       1/1     Running   3          15d   10.166.0.30   ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-ubus-kubeadm            1/1     Running   3          15d   10.166.0.30   ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
weave-net-l6b5x                        2/2     Running   9          15d   10.166.0.30   ubus-kubeadm   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: After describe, why Cluster IP addr and Endpoint addr are different?

Comment: This is describing a `kind: Service` whereas the endpoint IP comes from the `kind: Pod`