# Kubernetes API Server IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a K8S cluster with an Nginx ingress controller, linkerd, etc.

I want to apply strict network policies, like blocking ingress and egress connections in the entire namespace.

This works, but some services need access to the Kubernetes API server. Since I can't use the service domain `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` in my network policy, I must provide the full IP as CIDR.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-kube-server
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 1.2.3.4/32 # K8S API Endpoint
      ports:
        - port: 443
```

I got that IP thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016417)

Now, this cluster is not running 24/7, so it's shut down and restarted multiple times a week. This cause the K8S API IP to change on each restart, breaking my network policies, and I need to update the rules manually.

Is there any way to solve this issue, or do I need to start thinking about implementing some automation to update the policies after the restart?

Comment: is your issue resolved..? revert back here if you are still facing some issues..

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the traffic based on either **namespace** or **pod** label selectors as shown in the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). Just specify the labels of kube-apiserver's Pods.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  ingress:
    - from:
        - namespaceSelector:
            matchLabels:
              project: myproject
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              role: frontend
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 6379
```

Answer (score 0):

It is derived that your current environment is a test environment and you are testing out various features and plugins for deploying your application on kubernetes

> “Now, this cluster is not running 24/7, so it's shut down and
> restarted multiple times a week. This causes the K8S API IP to change
> on each restart, breaking my network policies, and I need to update
> the rules manually.”

Adding to the answer provided by `TAM` you can simply reserve your IP pools and assign them statically to your pods using calico plugin since it is just a test environment.

There are certain prerequisites for following this process: you need to install calico-ipam and also reserve a pool of IPs for static assignment, once these prerequisites are fulfilled you can configure static IP pools in your calico plugin and assign IPs manually to your pods.

Follow this [**calico official documentation**](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/networking/ipam/use-specific-ip) for more information on how to reserve IPs and statically assign them.